# Second Show Div Function Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use show div on click. But First One is working properly but not second one.

```
 <script type="text/livescript">
    function showDiv() {
      div = document.getElementById('change_pass');
      div.style.display = "block";
    }

function showDiv1() {    
      div = document.getElementById('invite-friend_now');
      div.style.display = "block";
    }
 </script>
```

And Using links onclick :

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:showDiv();">Change Password</a>

<a href="#" onclick="javascript:showDiv1();">Invite Friend</a>
```

On clicking Change Password, That division pop ups properly. But when we click on Invite Friend link, Page go to top and url shows `www.example.com/#` only.(....trailing `#` only)

Comment: It should work properly. Did you double checked div's id ? Or if you set it directly to be visible it is shown ?

Comment: Very same code or yours here: https://jsfiddle.net/fej9z1cs/ and it works.

Comment: could you add the divs in markup?

Comment: You really should return false too and change the useless `javascript:` to `return`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could be passing some parameter to use just one function. Also, you can use `preventDefault()` to prevent the page from scrolling up:

```
<script type="text/livescript">
    function showDiv(e, divName) {
      div = document.getElementById(divName);
      div.style.display = "block";
      e.preventDefault();
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="showDiv(event, 'change_pass');">Change Password</a>

<a href="#" onclick="showDiv(event, 'invite-friend_now');">Invite Friend</a>
```

Also, check on this `invite-friend_now` ID as I think you might have misspelled it.

Comment: my bad, I've just fixed it.

Comment: one more question, I am using php include for passwordchange.php and invitefriend.php.(both files are added in header.php) I have added require("class.phpmailer.php") in password.php file, it sends email perfectly. But when I added it invitefriend.php file, it shws error - my webpage contents are invisible..only background image is seen. And if I removed it, email nt getting send....

Comment: Humm, I'm a front-end developer, so I wouldn't know much about this php problem. I would suggest posting another question tagged with php so that our php colleagues can take a look at it.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is going to be easier by using jQuery this way:

```html
<button id="show_div">show div</button>
<div id="To_be_shown" style="display: none;"><p>some text</p></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $("#show_div").click(function () {
    $("#To_be_shown").fadeIn(100);
  });  
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery is not the answer to everything. To show and hide using .display is so simple there is no need for a library

Comment: Well, it is up to you.